# Git trying use proxy while operations with remote repository

Tags: git, proxy, atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting error like this

fatal: unable to access http://some_repo_addr : Failed to connect to some.proxy.addr.lan port 1080: Timed out
Pushing to http://some_repo_addr

Why my Git trying to use a proxy server while different operations with remote repository? Where Git got them? I mean that proxy settings. Cause I am delete all git options related to using proxy. Where from, Git take proxy server host, port and so on if it not specified in GIT options?

How I could force GIT do not use any proxy options?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, maybe this will help somebody

So if you have environment variable %http_proxy% in Windows then GIT will be
trying to use it, no matter which http.proxy setting in GIT you will set.